No "Inspect" group in Pixel Inspector
I've been trying to experiment with the Pixel Editor tool in order to take off some outlier elevations in order to my shaded relief maps.
However, my tools seem more limited than what I see in the tutorials. There is no "Inspect" group and under operations in the "Edit" group I don't see options for operations such as "Outlier Filter" that I see elsewhere.
I have the Image Analyst license and ArcGIS Pro is up to date (3.3.2). The rasters I'm using are TIFFs.
Is there something I am missing or need to do in order to get the full functionality of the Pixel Editor tool?
